# Value not updating in always@() block

Tags: verilog

```
reg [31:0] token_number_stall = 32'h00004daf;

always @ (posedge clk_host) begin

        if (reg_w_en) begin

            casez(reg_w_addr) 

                4'b0???:    token_number[reg_w_addr] <= reg_w_data;

                4'b100?:    token_number[reg_w_addr] <= reg_w_data;

            endcase 

        end
end

always @(posedge clk_net) begin

    for(subscription_index = 0; subscription_index < 10; subscription_index = subscription_index+1) begin

            if(token_number_stall ==token_number[subscription_index])
               
 trigger_flag_set <= 1;
            
else
               
 trigger_flag_set <= 0;
    
end

end
```

The problem that I'm facing with my code is that, on simulation if I use the `if` block to set `trigger_flag` and use a breakpoint, the code gets directed to the true case but `trigger_flag` remains 0. The value of the register does not update. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Verilog, you must remember that in an `always` block, everything happens in effectively zero-time. When the trigger occurs, in this case the positive edge of `clk_net`, then entire `for` loop statement will be evaluated immediately - this is done by the tools unrolling the loop.

You code:

```
always @(posedge clk_net) begin
  for(subscription_index = 0; subscription_index < 10; subscription_index = subscription_index+1) begin
    if(token_number_stall ==token_number[subscription_index])
      trigger_flag_set <= 1;        
    else           
      trigger_flag_set <= 0;  
    end
  end
end
```

Effectively becomes:

```
always @(posedge clk_net) begin
  if(token_number_stall == token_number[0])
    trigger_flag_set <= 1;        
  else           
    trigger_flag_set <= 0;  
  end
  if(token_number_stall == token_number[1])
    trigger_flag_set <= 1;        
  else           
    trigger_flag_set <= 0;  
  end
  ...
  if(token_number_stall == token_number[8])
    trigger_flag_set <= 1;        
  else           
    trigger_flag_set <= 0;  
  end
  if(token_number_stall == token_number[9])
    trigger_flag_set <= 1;        
  else           
    trigger_flag_set <= 0;  
  end
end
```

Notice how the final loop always sets `trigger_flag_set` regardless of its previous value. This means your code effectively optimises to:

```
always @(posedge clk_net) begin
  if(token_number_stall == token_number[9])
    trigger_flag_set <= 1;        
  else           
    trigger_flag_set <= 0;  
  end
end
```

All of the other conditions are ignored. That means if `trigger_flag_set` will only be high if `token_number[9]` is high.

In order to account for all of the cases, you need to change your logic a tad:

```
always @(posedge clk_net) begin
  trigger_flag_set <= 0;
  for(subscription_index = 0; subscription_index < 10; subscription_index = subscription_index+1) begin
    if(token_number_stall == token_number[subscription_index])
      trigger_flag_set <= 1;
    end
  end
end
```

Notice how now the flag is set to zero only at the start of the evaluation. Then as the loop is unrolled, we now set the flag if any of the conditions are met:

```
always @(posedge clk_net) begin
  trigger_flag_set <= 0;
  if(token_number_stall == token_number[0])
    trigger_flag_set <= 1;
  end
  if(token_number_stall == token_number[1])
    trigger_flag_set <= 1;
  end
  ...
  if(token_number_stall == token_number[8])
    trigger_flag_set <= 1;
  end
  if(token_number_stall == token_number[9])
    trigger_flag_set <= 1;
  end
end
```